# How does Rails populate the "model_type" field for polymorphic associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations, presenter

I have an Activity model. It `belongs_to :parent, :polymorphic => true`.

Does Rails use `parent.class.name`, `parent.model_name` or something else to populate the parent_type field?

I want a Presenter to behave like the parent object it wraps, and I need to override the right method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm working with Rails 3.0.7 right now, and the polymorphic type is being defined in `active_record-3.0.7/lib/active_record/association.rb`, line 1773.

```
def create_belongs_to_reflection(association_id, options)
  options.assert_valid_keys(valid_keys_for_belongs_to_association)
  reflection = create_reflection(:belongs_to, association_id, options, self)

  if options[:polymorphic]
    reflection.options[:foreign_type] ||= reflection.class_name.underscore + "_type"
  end

  reflection
end
```

So it looks like it is calling `class_name.underscore` and then appending "_type".  This may be slightly different for rails 3.1, but this should be a good starting place.

Comment: And `class_name` is defined as `@class_name ||= options[:class_name] || derive_class_name` if I'm not mistaken. `derive_class_name` is `name.to_s.camelize`. So I guess its just calling Model.name.to_s.camelize, and I should override the `name` method?

Comment: Pfff... actually it was working fine from scratch in the console, it's just that somewhere else in the code, someone created the object the wrong way, passing "explicitly" the :parent_type...