# ActiveRecord, find by polymorphic attribute

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, active-record-query

Having this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :historizable, :polymorphic => true
end

user = User.create!
```

I can:

```
Event.create!(:historizable => user)
```

But I can't:

```
Event.where(:historizable => user)
# Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'events.historizable' in 'where clause'
```

I have to do this instead:

```
Event.where(:historizable_id => user.id, :historizable_type => user.class.name)
```

### Update

Code that reproduces the issue: https://gist.github.com/fguillen/4732177#file-polymorphic_where_test-rb

Comment: I know I can do `user.events` if I have the `has_many` properly configured but I'm looking for the `where` possibility.

Comment: Just opened a bug in the rails project to see what they think: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9227

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This has been implemented in Rails master and will be available in
>   Rails 4. Thanks.

– [@carlosantoniodasilva](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9227)

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

```
user.events
```

This is a proper AR query, you can chain it with other scopes and stuff:

```
user.events.where(<your event conditions here>)
```

EDIT: AFAIK the other way around you must specify both fields (makes sense: you could have a user with id 4 and another thing with events, like a Party, also with id 4).

EDIT2: Regarding "Why does `create` work and `where` doesn't": `create` is more highlevel than `where`, because the former deals with "a complete model", while the latter manages things at the database table level.

1. ActiveRecord's `create` (AFAIK) uses a combination of `new` + `update_param` somewhere down the line.
2. `update_param` uses your model's `xxxx=` methods for assigning each individual property.
3. In your example, `historizable=` is a method built by the `belongs_to` expression. Since the `belongs_to` "knows" that it's polymorphic, it can deal with the type and id.

On the other hand, when you pass a hash to the `where` clause, the parameters there *only refer to database fields*. Rails provides scopes for "higher level" access:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  scope :by_historizable, lambda { |h| where(:historizable_id => h.id, :historizable_type => h.class.name) }

end

...

Event.by_historizable(user).where(<your other queries here>)
```

I've heard that this might change in Rails 4, and `where` might be more "intelligent". But I have not checked yet.

Comment: Hola @kikito, check my comment in the question, I was aware I can use the `User has_many` association to obtain the same result. But in my context this is not a possibility, I'm building a gem and I'm in charge of the `Event` implementation but not for the `historizable` object implementation which is out of my code so I can't blindly trust that the `has_many` has been properly defined.

Comment: About why do you need to specify both fields in the `where` but it works with only one in the `create` has not sense to me. The same _magic_ used in one method could be used in the oposite one.

Comment: Hola @fguillen, my first EDIT was my answer to your comment in the OP. I've added EDIT2 in response to your comments top this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the effort in the answer, but still my concerns remain. I don't want to use the _double param where_ because it is fragile due it is using not documented premises, like for example that the `_type` param is populated with `Class.name`, it looks like it is populated with `Class.name.to_s.camelize`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350037/how-does-rails-populate-the-model-type-field-for-polymorphic-associations#comment10299445_8350108 (the result is the same, but could be not)

Comment: _"This has been implemented in Rails master and will be available in Rails 4. Thanks."_ [@carlosantoniodasilva](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9227)

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
Event.joins(:historizable).where(:historizable => {:historizable_type => user})
```

Comment: `Can not eagerly load the polymorphic association :historizable`