# Activerecord : where clause with foreign attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, where-clause

I'd like to make sure of something.

I have two models `User` and `Comments` linked with a `belongs_to/has_many relationship`.

I can do this :

```
c = Comments.new
c.user = User.first
c.save
```

which is absolutely equivalent to

```
c = Comments.new
c.user_id = User.first.id
c.save
```

And sometimes I do

```
Comments.where(:user_id => User.first.id)
```

But I don't understand why I can't do

```
Comments.where(:user => User.first)
```

Activerecord and Rails are both supersmart, and in this very situation, I can't see any reason for not being able to write this, and any clean way around.

Comment: It sounds like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14753611/activerecord-find-by-polymorphic-attribute have you tried in Rails 4?

Comment: nice score you got there

Comment: Alright thanks. Too bad I'm using rails 3 ... Yeah nice score :)

Comment: I'll try to check how where is written in Rails 4 to - maybe - override it in my Rails 3 project. I'll report here for sure.